# jQuery - highlight effect problems

Tags: jquery, highlight, effect

I'm trying to use the jQuery effect(highlight) function like this:

```
$(".infoBarBoxButton").click(function(){
    $('#tilfojOpslagMain').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It's not doing anything at all. Do I need an extra jQuery file, or what's up? I've been reading the documentation on jQuery's web.

I am using Google's link: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

I've tried it with other div's too. What's wrong here? :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery UI library too...

You both of these:

```
  //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
  //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js
```

Not just

```
 //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
```

Code should look like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```